# mysql UPDATE not changing table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a made a form to allow for changing a users "UserLevel." However, I cannot seem to get it to work. It just is not changing the UserLevel after submit. I am definitely a PHP newbie. But I have tried researching this for the past hour and cannot seem to make any progress here. Probably something simple I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

### The form

```
<form action="dm/userUpdate.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="Username">
<br>
User Level: <input type="number" name="userlevel" value="0">

<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Change">
</form>
```

### userUpdate.php

```
<?php
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());


 $userlevel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userlevel"]);
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);


mysql_query($con,"UPDATE users SET UserLevel= $userlevel WHERE Username ='$username'");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing mysqli with mysql functions.Also is database really your database name?

Comment: I changed mysqli to mysql. No difference.

Comment: @Mihai If username is his real username and password is his real password then perhaps database is his real database name.

Comment: Its not a drop in replacement,there are differences.For example mysqli_select_db requires a connection http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp

Comment: @MennoGouw database its a reserved name,he should use back ticks.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Comment: @Mihai Just saying he named all of it like that so he does not show any to us which is smart in other words: I do not think his DB is called "database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape your variables. Or whatever this is called.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET UserLevel= '".$userlevel."' WHERE Username ='".$username."'");
```

Notice i used regular MySQL so no link is required as a parameter. If you are new to MySQL i advice to learn MySQLi right off the bat since it has some handy improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `mysqli` (note the **I**) and mysql (without an i) functions. The two libraries are **NOT** interchangeable.

As well, your SQL itself has syntax errors - `mysql_real_escape_string()` does **NOT** quote strings for you - it only escapes sql metacharacters, so you'll end up something like

```
... WHERE Username = Miles O\'Brien
```

instead of

```
... WHERE Username = 'Miles O\'Brien'
```

Comment: Ok so try removing  the 's ?

Comment: No. you need to add them. You have to build valid SQL... right now you're not

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET UserLevel= '$userlevel' WHERE Username ='$username'");
mysql_close();
```

you have no $con variable defined.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for syntax errors. Look at your table name and table fields and make sure they are spelled the same as well as cased.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("database", $con) or die(mysql_error());


 $userlevel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userlevel"], $con);
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"], $con);


mysql_query("UPDATE users SET UserLevel= " . $userlevel . " WHERE Username ='" . $username . "'", $con);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

use $con to hold connection link on connected data base and use mysql_query (not mysqli_query it is for MySQLi) and other functtions with that connection variable to work with connected database!